# Grunt not working: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gruntjs

I am trying to do this tutoral mean app:

https://youtu.be/a-dn6k6Frq4?t=4m47s

When I run grunt i keep getting this and hav no idea what it means or what to do:

meanBlog $ grunt

> > Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?
> >     (node:7760) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.

Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

> > 87 files lint free.

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task

> > 2 files lint free.

Running "mkdir:upload" task

Running "copy:localConfig" (copy) task

Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task

> > Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?
> >     Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
(node:7652) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
(node:6160) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
Debugger listening on [::]:5858


Could not connect to MongoDB!
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\code\meanBlog\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\code\meanBlog\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\code\meanBlog\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:177:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\debug-agent.cc:149: Assertion `(err) == (0)' failed.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You have two error. First look at the package.json and find grunt-node-inspector dependency. Second Your mongodb service is not runnig or not installed.

Comment: Fixed MongoDB was not installed hahahahahahahaha!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb was not installed.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```